# Android custom device camera permission

Tags: android, permissions, camera, external

I'm trying to fix a problem wherein a custom Android device(sort of PDA) has an external camera attached. When I open the 'Camera' app, the camera works fine, but other apps such as Skype etc are unable to access that camera.

So being new to the kernel/hardware side of Android, do I have to change some permissions and re-compile the OS or can it be fixed in some other way.

Any help is much appreciated,

Cheers,
Keith

Answer (score 1):

You have to add Camera permissions for those app which need to access Camera and are unable to access it.

Comment: But I thought we cannot change manifest files of other apps? Can we?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added these permissions in Manifest file?

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: But to which app's manifest would I need to add this? Skype and other apps are unable to access the camera but the 'Camera' app can access it.

Answer (score 0):

> Cameras are a resource that is shared by applications on a device.
>   Your application can make use of the camera after getting an instance
>   of Camera, and you must be particularly careful to release the camera
>   object when your application stops using it, and as soon as your
>   application is paused (Activity.onPause()). If your application does
>   not properly release the camera, all subsequent attempts to access the
>   camera, including those by your own application, will fail and may
>   cause your or other applications to be shut down.

Please read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Comment: The catch is that there is no application that I've written or used for development. The only thing I did is attach an external camera to the device. The 'Camera' app is able to use that external camera but other apps like Skype, Instagram, iCam etc cannot access that external camera